# Generic Resource approach in python compared to PHP

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm new at python and as my first experience i'm developing a REST API with flask-RESTful.

Suddenly i want to create a superclass which handle the basics for most used http verbs but i figure that it is more difficult compared to PHP.

So the objective is to have a Resource class that implements the functions: get(), post(), put() and delete().

In PHP it will look like:

```php
trait RESTActions
{
  public function get($id)
    {
        $m = self::MODEL;
        $model = $m::find($id);
        if (is_null($model)) {
            return $this->respond(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return $this->respond(Response::HTTP_OK, $model);
    }
  }

class ProfessionsController extends Controller
{

  const MODEL = "App\Profession";

  use RESTActions;

}

class Profession extends Model
{

    public static $rules = [
        // Validation rules
    ];
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $dates = [];

    // Relationships

}
```

This get will work for every controller that implements "use RESTActions;"

In python i figure that would sound like:

```py
from flask_restful import Resource

class Resource(Resource):
    model = None

    def get(self, name):
        obj = model.get(name)
        if obj:
            return obj.json()
        return {'message': 'Not found'}, 404




from resources.resource import Resource
from models.store import StoreModel

class Store(Resource):
    model = StoreModel

    def get(self):
        super().get(name)



from db import db

class StoreModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'stores'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(80))

items = db.relationship('ItemModel', lazy='dynamic')


def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.items = None

@classmethod
def get(cls, name):
    return cls.query.filter_by(name=name).first()
```

With this i expected to access Store.get(name) -> Resource.get(self, name) -> StoreModel.get(cls, name)

But it doesn't run that way

I can reach Resource.get() but model doesn't have a valid class reference to call StoreModel.get()

I need a way to reference the "ClassModel" which must be given in the subclass that allows me to call the "ClassModel" methods and that reference may be StoreModel, ItemModel, AnythingModel as the subclass is Store, Item, Anything respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

There was a place where i was calling StoreModule instead of StoreModel
It works!!!